# how to copy specifc data in one user table to another user table

Tags: sql

I need transfer specific data’s from one user table to another user table .I tried below code it worked but copied all the data’s but i need only specific datas to be copied

```
Insert into sys.book (select * from syste.mytable);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put a `WHERE` clause on the `SELECT` to say what values you want:

```
INSERT INTO sys.book 
SELECT * FROM syste.mytable
WHERE column1 = valueThatYouWantInTableBook
```

Comment: k. but i need insert multiple data's which differ from each other

Comment: like if i give where name="shyam" that row only get inserted

Comment: You can put multiple validations in the where clause to cover that. Or if you want to insert multiple names you can do `WHERE name IN ('shyam','john','peter',....)`